# package my first Blackberry widget. - xml file not found

Tags: blackberry, widget, packaging

I am trying to package my first Blackberry widget. as described on Blackberry site:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/10593/BlackBerry_widget_samples_Hello_world.pdf

I edited files in Eclipse and an trying to create a .cod file with command line packaging tool.

Contents of zip files include config.xml

```
 Directory of C:\trash\hello

12/13/2010  03:11 PM    <DIR>          .
12/13/2010  03:11 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/29/2009  02:09 PM               544 config.xml
12/13/2010  03:11 PM                 0 file.txt
09/29/2009  02:31 PM               648 index.html
12/13/2010  02:32 PM    <DIR>          Scripts
12/13/2010  02:32 PM    <DIR>          Styles
               3 File(s)          1,192 bytes

 Directory of C:\trash\hello\Scripts

12/13/2010  02:32 PM    <DIR>          .
12/13/2010  02:32 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/29/2009  02:32 PM               172 action.js
               1 File(s)            172 bytes

 Directory of C:\trash\hello\Styles

12/13/2010  02:32 PM    <DIR>          .
12/13/2010  02:32 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/29/2009  02:15 PM                14 simple.css
               1 File(s)             14 bytes
```

However widget packeger cannot find config.xml file.

```
C:\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Widget Packager>bbwp c:\trash\trash\hello.zip
[INFO]                  Parsing command line options
[INFO]                  Parsing bbwp.properties
[INFO]                  Validating widget archive
[ERROR]                 Invalid widget archive - failed to find config.xml
```

Comment: Found the problem. config.xml had to be in the root when the zip file is restored. It was in a subdirectory, so the packager indeed could not find it where it was expecting to find it....

Comment: FYI, you can actually answer your own question and then accept the answer.  That way you get some more rep, and the question will show up as solved, which is useful.  Cheers!